# Praying to saints

Tags: catholicism, origin, intercession-of-saints

As I understand it in The Roman Catholic Church, you pray to the saints.
Since Christianity has it's roots in Judaism, are there any stories that tell us that Israel did the same, for example, praying to Jakov or any other great father of the faith? If not, why did the RCC start to do this?

(not a dupe)

Comment: To note, we ask saints to pray **to God** *for us*, whether they be alive in heaven or on earth. (We are not praying to the saints; we are asking them to pray for us.)

Comment: @Geremia Not the same,I almost wrote that in my question

Comment: Did Moses ask Abraham to pray for him?Did anyone do  that before Christ?

Comment: You can see almost everything if not evreything in the new testament in the old,but where is praying to the saints?Talmud? Where?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate... Aigle is asking for specific information about _if there is any historical evidence of prayer to saints in ancient Judaism_. He is not asking the more general question of why Catholics pray to Saints. I would vote to unlock this if I could

Answer (score 0):

One starting point would be 1 Thessalonians, 4:14

> For since we believe that Jesus died and rose again, even so, through Jesus, God will bring with him those who have fallen asleep. [RSV]

For a Catholic, a Saint is someone whose life bears witness that they have already risen again, and are declared to have been already judged, and found to be sufficiently holy that they are already in heaven with God, living eternal life in Heaven. The people who are in Heaven, are alive, just like you and I are, and not dead. Such individuals would not only include Jakov (Jacob) the patriarch, and the other Patriarchs of—Abraham, Israel, Isaac, and Moses (among others) but more recent individuals, including David the King, and much more recent individuals such as Theresa of Calcutta. Because these people are not dead, but alive eternally in God's presence, the Church calls them Saints. Because they are alive, asking for them for "favors" on our behalf, or on the behalf of others, is not considered to be praying to the dead, but rather the same as someone asking you to pray for them.

Comment: Please consider moving your answer to the canonical one which this is now a duplicate of.

Comment: @curiousdannii  There is no DUPE! The question is,why did they start to do this IF NOT A PART OF  JEWISH HISTORY!??